# Python kivy gameover label text

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making a game in kivy, and I have a Label with a text that says "GAME OVER" I want this text to appear whenever the game is over and disappear whenever I click on "start game". How can I do that? I tried a lot but can't seem to find any solution, Any help is appreciated! Thank You so much! Below is my code!

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

    def play_sound(self):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('button press sound.wav.')
        if sound:
            sound.play()


sound = SoundLoader.load('Crowd sound effect.wav')
sound.loop = True
sound.play()


class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

    def play_sound(self):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('button press sound.wav.')
        if sound:
            sound.play()


class Ball(Image):
    velocity = NumericProperty(0)



    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if Vector(self.center).distance(touch.pos) <= 33:
            label = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('game_screen').ids.score
            label.text = str(int(label.text) + 1)
            sound = SoundLoader.load('Soccer ball sound.wav')
            sound.play()
            self.source = "icons/ball.png"
            self.velocity = 275
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if Vector(self.center).distance(touch.pos) <= 33:
            self.source = "icons/ball.png"
        return super().on_touch_up(touch)


class MainApp(App):
    GRAVITY = 300


    def move_ball(self, time_passed):
        ball = self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball
        ball.y = ball.y + ball.velocity * time_passed
        ball.velocity = ball.velocity - self.GRAVITY * time_passed
        self.check_collision()

    def check_collision(self):
        ball = self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball
        if ball.top < 96:
            self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.score.text = "0"
            self.game_over()


    def game_over(self):
        self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball.pos = (0, (0.5) )
        print("game over")
        self.frames.cancel()
        self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.start_button.disabled = False
        self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.start_button.opacity = 1


    def next_frame(self, time_passed):
        self.move_ball(time_passed)


    def start_game(self):
        #Clock.schedule_interval(self.move_ball, 1/60.)
        self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball.velocity = 275
        self.frames = Clock.schedule_interval(self.next_frame, 1/60.)
        self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.score.text = "0"


    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        self.root.current = screen_name



MainApp().run()
```

homescreen.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition


<HomeScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#39B3F2")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .9
            Image:
                source: "icons/keepyup.png"
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                font_size: dp(20)
                font_name: 'SackersGothicStd-Medium.otf'
                text: "PLAY"
                color: "gold"
                pos_hint: { "center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
                size: 80, 55
                size_hint: None, None
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: (57/255.0, 179/255.0, 242/255.0, .10)


                on_press:

                on_release:
                    root.play_sound()
                    root.manager.transition = FadeTransition()
                    app.change_screen("game_screen")
```

gamescreen.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils


<GameScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#39B3F2")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .1
            Image:
                source: "icons/sun.png"
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .2
            Image:
                source: "icons/clouds.png"
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            pos_hint: {"bottom": 1, "left": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .5
            Image:
                source: "icons/Field4.png"
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
                pos: self.pos

        Label:
            id: score
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: dp(25)
            font_name: 'SackersGothicStd-Medium.otf'
            text: "0"
            color: "gold"
            pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.9}



        Label:
            id: over
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: dp(25)
            font_name: 'SackersGothicStd-Medium.otf'
            text: "GAME OVER!"
            color: "gold"
            outline_color: "white"
            outline_width: 1
            pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.6}



        Button:
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: dp(20)
            font_name: 'SackersGothicStd-Medium.otf'
            text: "Start Game"
            color: "gold"
            pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.3}
            size: 150, 55
            size_hint: None, None
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (57/255.0, 179/255.0, 242/255.0, .10)
            id: start_button
            on_release:
                self.disabled = True
                self.opacity = 0
                root.play_sound()
                app.start_game()


        Ball:
            source: "icons/ball.png"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 500, 500
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            id: ball
```

main.kv

```
#:include kv/homescreen.kv
#:include kv/gamescreen.kv


ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    HomeScreen:
        name: "home_screen"
        id: home_screen
    GameScreen:
        name: "game_screen"
        id: game_screen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just modify the `opacity` of the `Label`. In your `start_game()` method, set the `opacity` to 0:

```
def start_game(self):
    #Clock.schedule_interval(self.move_ball, 1/60.)
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball.velocity = 275
    self.frames = Clock.schedule_interval(self.next_frame, 1/60.)
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.score.text = "0"
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.over.opacity = 0
```

And in the `game_over()` method, set the opacity to 1:

```
def game_over(self):
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball.pos = (0, (0.5) )
    print("game over")
    self.frames.cancel()
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.start_button.disabled = False
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.start_button.opacity = 1
    self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.over.opacity = 1
```

Comment: this worked but whenever I'm in the game screen its shows up how can I make it so that In the game screen it's not there

Comment: Set `opacity: 0` for the `Label` in the `kv`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Label I'd recommend using a Popup for this.
You can define that the popup will close after clicking and will remove and re-add widgets to a main layout on which all the other game-play related layouts will reside

Here's my example:
*main.py*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class GameOverApp(App):
    pass

# The main layout
class MyMainLayout(BoxLayout):

    def game_over(self):
        # creating a button
        btn = Button(text="Restart")
        # Creating a popup and adding the button to it
        # auto_dismiss means that clicking anywhere else won't close the popup
        my_popup = Popup(title="Game over!", content=btn, auto_dismiss=False)
        # binding two functions, one for restarting the game and one for closing the popup
        btn.bind(on_press=self.restart_game)
        btn.bind(on_press=my_popup.dismiss)
        # open the popup
        my_popup.open()

    def restart_game(self, event):
        # Clear all widgets from the mainlayout and re-initialize them
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(GameLayout())


# the layout which holds all the game items
class GameLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

GameOverApp().run()
```

*gameover.kv*

```
MyMainLayout:

<MyMainLayout>
    GameLayout:
    Button:
        text: "Click me for game over"
        on_press: self.parent.game_over()

<GameLayout>
    Label:
        text: "game data..."
```

[Popups with floatlayouts](https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/kivy-tutorial/popup-windows/)

[Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html)